# Access to modified closure warning for value type?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following code

```
public static TResult Run<TResult>(Task<TResult> task, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    bool isOperationCancelled = false;
    var resultTask = task.ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        //isOperationCancelled is warned for Access to modified closure.
        if (!isOperationCancelled&& !t.IsCanceled && !t.IsFaulted)
            return t.Result;
        else
            throw new TaskCanceledException(t);
    }, CancellationToken.None);

    try
    {
        CheckAndStartTask(task);
        resultTask.Wait(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (AggregateException aggregateException)
    {
        aggregateException.Handle(ex => ex is TaskCanceledException);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
        isOperationCancelled = true;
    }

    return resultTask.Result;
}
```

I am expecting the value for `isOperationCancelled` to be changed and it is a local variable.
Why do I get the warning, I have tried passing the field as the `Task`'s state object but still the warning does not go away ?
I am aware of modified closure across threads but in this case I am expecting a value to set from a different thread(waiting thread in this case).

I tried refactoring like below still the warning is not gone.

```
bool isOperationCancelled = false;

//isOperationCancelled inside Func body is warned for Access to modified closure.
var operationCancelled = new Func<bool>(() => isOperationCancelled);

var resultTask = task.ContinueWith((t, opCancld) =>
{
    if (!((Func<bool>)opCancld)() && !t.IsCanceled && !t.IsFaulted)
        return t.Result;
    else
        throw new TaskCanceledException(t);
}, operationCancelled, CancellationToken.None);
```

I can think of one scenario when the result task is executed before the `isOperationCancelled` is set from the waiting thread.
Am I missing anything else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a warning given by ReSharper, you can safely ignore it if you know what you're doing. You can also suppress it by adding the comment `// Resharper disable AccessToModifiedClosure` on the previous line.

Comment: thanks, but is there anyway I can make the warning go away by refactoring ?

Comment: You don't need to refactor your code. The behavior described by the warning is exactly *what you want*, since the variable will be set from the outside.

Comment: @Vignesh.N, as Yuval said, you don't need to. The warning is there only in case you didn't realize what your code was doing.